# What are the differences between keypress and change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to java script. I am bit confused about key-press and change event.

Following is sample code

```
 $("input").live('change',function ()
    {
       Alert("Change event call");
    });

    /
    $("input").live('keypress',function ()
    {            
       Alert("Keypress event call");
    });
```

When exactly Keypress event is call and change event call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Change event

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

### Keypress event

> The `keypress` event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event, except in the
>   case of key repeats. If the user presses and holds a key, a `keydown`
>   event is triggered once, but separate `keypress` events are triggered
>   for each inserted character. In addition, modifier keys (such as
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>) trigger `keydown` events but not `keypress` events.
>
> A `keypress` event handler can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can
>   vary between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

**References:**

- http://api.jquery.com/change/
- http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 4):

The change event occurs if the value has been changed when the element loses focus. The keypress event occurs every time you press down and release a (non control) key.

Answer (score 1):

`keypress` implies that you just clicked a keyboard key

`change` implies that you have changed the value of an item

Answer (score 0):

Well some keys could be pressed, and the value still wouldn't change. For example if you press enter, or ctrl the value of input would not change.

Answer (score 0):

Keypress event is triggered each time a keyboard key is pressed.
Change is called when the control loses focus.